# SqlBulkCopy is slow. What should I do?

Tags: c#

I want to insert 2 million rows from a dataTable into SQL Server, but it takes a lot of time.

Here is my code

```
DataTable tbl_xml = new DataTable();

var xmlFilePath = (Server.MapPath("~/") + FileUpload1.FileName);//Location of the XML file.

DataSet dsCameraDetails = new DataSet();
dsCameraDetails.ReadXml(xmlFilePath);// Load XML in dataset

dtl = dsCameraDetails.Tables["Row"];
dtl.Columns.Add("state", typeof(string));
int countfile = dtl.Rows.Count;

SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["azmoonak"].ConnectionString);
SqlBulkCopy bulk2 = new SqlBulkCopy(con2);
bulk2.DestinationTableName = "tbl_xml";

try
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dtl.Columns)
        bulk2.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
}
catch(Exception eee)
{
}

con2.Open();

try
{
    bulk2.BulkCopyTimeout = 1000;
    bulk2.WriteToServer(dtl);
}
catch(Exception eee)
{
}

con2.Close();
```

Actually I want to read data from a huge xml file and insert it into SQL Server in a short time. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What is your SQL technology?  and SSIS packages for SQL are great/made for large data transfers like this.

Comment: Doi not try to do the operation in C#. Do it in SQL on the SQL server.

Comment: Avoid those empty try-catches.

Comment: Loading a huge XML file into memory may have a performance impact before you even start the bulk copy.  Consider using an XmlReader to read the Xml sequentially without loading it all into memory, and wrap it with a custom IDataReader implementation that you can pass to SqlBulkCopy.  Google will help you get started on the IDataReader implementation.

Comment: I would suggest multithread also divide the process in small chunks of 100k to process each time